# Colored screen when booting raspbian from noobs

Tags: raspbian, kernel, screen, boot-issues, noobs

i have a raspberry pi model b with noobs and raspbian installed on the sd card. ive used it for quite a while but today when i boot the pi it just shows me a colored screen and i cant do anything. i was looking around and someone suggested it was the kernel.img but i have no idea how to get to the kernel.img with noobs installed. is there any way to even get my files off of this sd card because i see no place for my os or anywhere is could be.

Comment: This might be so. I have posted my Kernel image. http://goo.gl/ba0xln

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting which outlines a systematic process for diagnosing problems. Post what you find if you need further halp.

I had a similar issue when I first got a Pi which I fixed by adding a file called config.txt containing “hdmi_edid_file=1″ to the SD card before you first boot it (after copy the NOOBS files onto it).

It is unclear from your question what system you have. It is relatively easy to check the `boot` partition in OS X, Windows or Linux, but a bit harder to get at the `ext4` Raspbian partition.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after displaying the splash screen, the PI starts consuming a little more current. If the PI resets at that moment, it is an indication that the power supply isn't able to deliver the full current your PI requires, but dips its output voltage below a minimum when loaded with the full current the PI needs.

Try replacing the power supply

Comment: I doubt the colored screen is caused by a bad power supply.  My power supply is perfect, and the issue is that the Noobs card contains an outdated version of OS, not compatible with PI 3.