# Pi not booting properly

Tags: boot

When I boot up my Raspberry Pi a rainbow screen comes up followed with a bunch of words I am not familiar with and the words do not change.

My power LED is red and the top green light flashes about four to five times.

I have a raspberry Pi Model B and I am using NOOBS.

Comment: Have a look through http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting to see if your problem is covered.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what words come up and what you mean by "not familiar with?" It is a little difficult to understand your problem as written.

Comment: I fixed it by gettimg noobs on my sd card again I think the problem was that I turned my pi on without turning it off properly.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem a "rainbow screen" see [Colored screen when booting raspbian from noobs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22407/8697)

This suggests various troubleshooting options. I had a similar issue when I first got a Pi which I fixed by adding a file called config.txt containing “hdmi_edid_file=1″ to the SD card before you first boot it (after copy the NOOBS files onto it).

It is unclear from your question what system you have. It is relatively easy to check the boot partition in OS X, Windows or Linux.

I think the issue has since been fixed in NOOBS. I really don't understand why NOOBS is recommended. Most people only use it to install Rasbian. It is no harder to directly install this, and doesn't waste ~2GB of your SD Card.

Comment: At least for sometime in the past, the Raspbian on NOOBS wasn't identical. I was using the one from NOOBS a while back because it's cec wasn't broken.