# Raspberry pi B+ first boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues, noobs, firmware

I got Raspberry pi B+ and I tried to boot by using NOOBS v1.3.10 and RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy Version:September 2014. Then I got two different problems.

---

These are my component information,

1. Raspberry pi B+
2. 5V 2A power supply
3. SanDisk Ultra 16Gb class 10 micro SD card
4. HDMI cable plug to Samsung Smart TV

---

When I boot the Raspberry pi B+ by using **NOOBS v1.3.10** I got **color screen and it load again and again** like below photo. I downloaded NOOBS v1.3.10 and unzip it. After that format the micro SD card by using SDFormatter. ( Run in administrator and using format size adjustment ON ). Then copy files from unzip folder to SD card and boot it up.

[image]

How to **solve** this problem ? Can you explain **step by step** ?

---

When I boot the Raspberry pi B+ by using **RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy Version:September 2014** I got **color screen after that load some cord and it load again and again** like below photo. I downloaded RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy Version:September 2014 and unzip it. After that format the micro SD card by using SDFormatter. ( Run in administrator and using format size adjustment ON ). Then run in administrator the Win32DiskImager and choose the img file from unzip file. Then write to SD card. After that boot it up.

This is the video I saw this problem [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04OEcZMxyl0)

[image]

How to **solve** this problem ? Can you explain **step by step** ?

Comment: How are you copying the files to the sd card (what software, process are you using)? Detailed instructions are available here http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_NOOBS

Comment: yeah i use these methods. Format and just copy and paste to SD card then it show color screen and run again and again

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found the problem that is my power supply. It is not 5V output it is around 6.8V that is why color screen after that load some cord and it load again and again. If you find how to check voltage Raspberry pi B+ and B this is the [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3RPzBszaBA) I founded. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have 2 questions (although I am not sure what the 2nd actually is). Separate these into distinct questions.

Your problem 1 is "rainbow screen" see [Colored screen when booting raspbian from noobs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22407/8697)

This suggests various troubleshooting options. I had a similar issue when I first got a Pi which I fixed by adding a file called config.txt containing “hdmi_edid_file=1″ to the SD card before you first boot it (after copy the NOOBS files onto it).